# Why is '==' not working in PHP?

Tags: php

Both values are '2' but I am not getting a true. Why?

```
 echo $getuser. "<br />"; 
 echo $userurl. "<br />"; 
   if ($getuser == $userurl) {  
       echo "true <br />";
     }
```

Result

```
2
2
```

Comment: I don't know php, but maybe one of those is a string and the other an integer?

Comment: @house9: PHP will convert them to the same types to check them for '==', you have to use '===' to do a type-specific comparison.

Comment: If the code above started with $getuser = 2 and $geturl = 2, would you get a true response?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of echoing them out, use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) to see exactly what is stored in those variables:

```
var_dump($getuser); echo "<br />";
var_dump($userurl); echo "<br />";
```

Comment: I get 'string(1) "2" string(7) "2"'

Comment: ok I know where they are coming from. I strip a URL from '/users/3104' to '3104' so I get rid of 7 chars by using '$userurl = substr($users['url'],7). "<br />";' I tried using trim($userurl, "\0") to get rid of NULL bytes but it's not working.

Comment: found the solution: '$userurl = ltrim($users['url'], " users/" );' Thanks!

Comment: Yep, gotta remember that with browser-based debugging, it's WYSIPNWYPI  (what you see is probably not what you put in)

Comment: @patrick: I don't think, that you want to do `ltrim($users['url'], " users/" )` (read carefully the docs: http://php.net/ltrim ). Apart from that, you should accept the answer, if it solved your problem (or put you on the right track).

Answer (score 4):

You probably have some stray spaces or other characters which are not easy, or maybe not possible to visually detect.

use

```
var_dump($getuser);
var_dump($userurl);
```

Pay attention to the string length. Consider using trim() if needed

Comment: +1 for specifically calling out whitespace.  That was my hunch as well.

Answer (score 3):

may be contain dummy space in that, use like this

```
 echo $getuser. "<br />"; 
 echo $userurl. "<br />"; 
   if (trim($getuser) == trim($userurl)) {  
       echo "true <br />";
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

When I try

```
$getuser = 2;
$userurl = 2;

echo $getuser. "<br />";
echo $userurl. "<br />";
if ($getuser == $userurl) {
    echo "true <br />";
}
```

Results:

```
2
2
true
```

Works for me. On XAMPP (Windows) and Linux (Apache) alike. So there's problem probably somewhere in configuration or something...